# NotificationManager.notify() not launching full-screen intent when screen is on

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have an alarm clock app and since android 10 I have to use full-screen intents to trigger the alarms. When the device is off everything works great, but when the device is on it just shows a message at the top of the screen which the user can click on, and then it navigates to the screen it was supposed to launch automatically. Here is the code:

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { // This is at least android 10...

            if (mgr.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER) == null) {
                mgr.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_WHATEVER,
                        context.getString(R.string.alarms_channel_name), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH));
                }

                mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, buildNormal(context, i).build());

            } else { // This is android 9 or below...

                context.startActivity(i);

            }
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder buildNormal(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder b =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_WHATEVER);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(context.getString(R.string.message, context.getString(R.string.alarms_channel_name))))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.message, context.getString(R.string.alarms_channel_name)))
            .setFullScreenIntent(buildPendingIntent(context, intent), true);

    return (b);

}

private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {

    return (PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}
```

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you feel is an issue? Everything seems to be behaving as documented.

Comment: @CommonsWare The issue is that if the user goes to sleep with the screen on, the alarm won't go off. I need somehow to wake the user even if the screen is on.

Comment: "the alarm won't go off" -- sorry, but I do not know what you mean by this. Do you mean that your ringtone is not playing?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes. It means that the screen of the alarm (which also plays the ringtone) won't appear.

Comment: Put your ringtone in the notification. (or, more accurately, in the notification channel on newer devices)

Comment: @ I don't get it. Can you please show an example?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes)

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added notificationChannel.setSound(mAlarm.getAlarmTone(),  new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                                .build()); But it's still playing the default notification beep sound.

Comment: You cannot change an existing channel. So, you may need to set up a different channel and start using it. Also, `setSound()` has [its own set of issues](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html), depending on what your `Uri` looks like.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. It's working now.